# How can this function have an associate function?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, definition, quotient-spaces, adjoint-functors

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology:

---

> $(\Sigma, \Omega)$ is an adjoint pair of functors in $\text{hTop}_*$, where $\Sigma$ is the reduced suspension and $\Omega$ is the Loop space operator.

PROOF:

If $X$ and $Y$ are pointed spaces, define $\tau_{XY}=[\Sigma X, Y] \rightarrow [X, \Omega Y]$ by $[F] \rightarrow [F^\text{#}]$ where $F^\text{#}$ means the associate function.

---

How can this function have an associate function?  Associate functions are defined as followed:

If $F : Z \times Y \rightarrow X$ is a function, then its associate is the function $F^\text{#}:Z \rightarrow \text{Hom}(Y,X)$ defined by $F^\text{#}(z)=F_z$ (where $F_z: y \rightarrow F(z,y)$)

But $\Sigma X = X \times I / (X \times \dot I \cup \{x_0\} \times I)$ (where $x_0$ is the basepoint of $X$) is not of this form and therefore an associate function should not be defined here.

Can someone explain to me what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

A map from $\Sigma X$ to $Y$ induces a map from $X\times I$ to $Y$
(by composing with the projection from $X\times I$ to $\Sigma X$), and that has an associate: a map from $X$ to $\Omega Y$.

Comment: If $p : X \times I \rightarrow \Sigma X$ and $F: \Sigma X \rightarrow Y$, then $Fp : X \times I \rightarrow Y$ has an associate which maps $X \rightarrow \Omega Y$, but how does this composition show that $F$ has an associate in the function defined in the question?

$[Fp] \mapsto [(Fp)^{\text{#}}]$ is a map from $[X \times I, Y] \rightarrow [X, \Omega Y]$.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how this shows that $[F]$ has an associate?  I still don't understand how it's possible since an associate is not defined on a quotient space.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very close relationship between $\Sigma X$ and $X \times I$. There is a similarly close relationship between $\Omega Y$ and $Y^I$. These relationships are so close that it's often not worth commenting when passing back and forth between them: the reader is expected to fill in those minor details.

The proof gives the formula for the isomorphism in terms of the adjunction $[X \times I, Y] \to [X, Y^I]$. You, the reader, are expected to fill in both of the aforementioned relationships to turn this into a function $[\Sigma X, Y] \to [X, \Omega Y]$ (and you're expected to check the result is well-defined).